# Слетел перевод у checkbox'а при создании вопроса/ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> Email me new responses to my posts
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то я не вижу этого чекбокса. В каких ситуациях он появляется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

> Отправлять новые ответы на мои сообщения по почте

Такой же как был (а может ещё и где-то есть) на фразу:

> Send me new responses to my posts via email

Будет доступно после подгрузки transifex и пересборки сайта.